# how to call python function and pass arguments when the html button is clicked?

Tags: python, flask

I displayed the data's from database

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <article class="media content-section">
            <div class="table-responsive">          
                <div class="table table-striped">
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Phone Number</th>
                                <th> Send SMS </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        {% for detail in details%}
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th>{{ detail.username }}</th>
                                <th>{{ detail.phonenumber }}</th>
                                <th><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="'{{ url_for('sendsms', phonenumber = detail.phonenumber)}}'">Send Request</button></th>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                {% endfor %}
            </table>
        </div>
    </article>
{% endblock content %}
```

HOW TO CALL THE FUNCTION AND PASS THE PHONE NUMBER WHEN THE BUTTON IS CLICKED?

When i pressed that button the sendsms function should called and the phonenumber should passed to this function.

My Route is

```
def sendsms(phonenumber):
        account_sid = '************************'
        auth_token = '*************************'
        client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

        message = client.messages.create(
                                  from_= current_user.username,
                                  body='i need immediately'
                                  to= phonenumber)

        print(message.sid)
```

Comment: You can wrap this values in an html form which will trigger a POST request to your "sendsms" endpoint on backend. This could be also done using JS.

Comment: Thank you Vladimir Vishnevskyi. May you please show any example??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, let's go. First, let's add form elements to your HTML code.

```
{% for detail in details%}

#let's make a bunch of forms for every detail so you can send separate data for every request.

    <form action="{{ url_for('sendsms') }}" method="post">
        <tbody>
           <tr>
          <th><input type="text" name="username" value={{ detail.username }} required></th>
          <th><input type="text" name="phonenumber" value={{ detail.phonenumber }} required></th>
          <th><input type="submit" name="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Send Request"></a></th>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
    </form>
        {% endfor %}
```

Afterwards let's make our backend process POST requests.

```
#Let's make sure that our route handles POST requests so add POST method to route:
@app.route('/sendsms', methods=['POST'])
def sendsms():
    account_sid = '************************'
    auth_token = '*************************'
    client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

    #You can access values you sent in form using request.form data:
    phonenumber = request.form['phonenumber']
    username = request.form['username']

    message = client.messages.create(
                              from_= username,
                              body='i need immediately'
                              to= phonenumber)

    print(message.sid)
```

P.S. This code probably should work, but since i can't check it - this will at least give you a hint. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much Vladimir Vishnevskyi

Comment: @Tamilselvan If this answer helped you, you should [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)